# Undoing several merge commits in git

Tags: git, git-merge

Having some problems with undoing git merges. What happend:

- Both topic and beta is branched from master but topic is branched later than beta.
- Developer 1 (D1) makes changes to beta
- Developer 2 (D2) creates a topic branch, makes some commits and merge it into beta
- When merging D2 gets conflicts because B and C has changes in the same files as D, E and F
- D2 chooses the changes in the topic branch by doing git checkout --theirs & git add/commit
- D2 pushes his changes to origin
- D2 makes another commit, merges it, then another commit and merges that too (without problems)
- D2 pushes those changes to origin too
- D1 runs git pull
- D1 complains that changes he made on beta has been overwritten

  ```
      X---D---E---F---M1--M2--M3 beta
     /               /   /   /
    /       X---X---X---X---X topic
   /       /
  A---B---C---X---X master
  ```

I read some stackoverflow questions and asked in #git and ended up running git revert -m 1 M3, git revert -m 1 M2 and git revert -m 1 M1. D1 was happy that his changes was back.

I now thought I could git merge topic into beta but this time choose git checkout --ours but I couldn't because nothing happend. I read https://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/howto/revert-a-faulty-merge.txt but still don't understand everything 100%.

I ended up running rebasing all my topic commits into only one commit which I could then merge into beta.

What I'm wondering is if there's an easier way to solve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason that you weren't able to merge in topic a second time was because the changes are already present in the history and git has nothing to bring in to the branch.  When you did the `git revert` to undo the merges, you created new commits.  These commits are the inverse of the merge commits that were done already.  The branch beta has the changes from topic undone but the commits are still in the history so when you tried to merge again, there is nothing to merge.  You "undid" the commit by making a new one that changes the files to back to how they were.

This is what your branches now look like

```
    X---D---E---F---M1--M2--M3--R1--R2--R3 beta
   /               /   /   /
  /       X---X---X---X---X topic
 /       /
A---B---C---X---X master
```

R1, R2, and R3 are the revert commits for the merges that you have.

The easier way to have solved it would have been to have D2 properly resolve the merge conflict.  The changes from D1 were stomped on when they did a checkout of their files and committed them.

If it does happen again, the best way to resolve it is to create a new commit that resolves the conflict correctly.  As long as the person resolving the merge conflicts doesn't commit using the `-m` option, git appends the files that had conflicts in the merge commit.  You would be able then use `git log -p -m {MERGE SHA} {FILE}` and you can see what the changes in the file are and correct them.

To bring in the changes from topic, you will have to do it manually.  You can get the list of files that are different by doing `git diff --name-only beta topic`.  Then bring the files to beta yourself by doing `git checkout topic -- <files>` and then committing them.

Comment: So, to be clear, `git checkout -b wip M1^1; git merge M1^2` to create the correct merge result, then `git merge -s ours M1` to get the correct merge base, then it's a straightforward `git checkout -B beta M3; git merge wip`.

Comment: I am not sure about the `git merge -s ours M1` step, but that might work.  Though it seems to creating some extra commits that will be difficult to track.

Comment: I remember that the commit message of the merge did have the files that had conflicts but looking at `git log` now it only says "Merge branch 'topic' into beta`.